# How to log contents in realm

Tags: java, android, realm

Hi I have added data to my realm but I have not written the codes to display it as of now. The app runs without crashing. Now, before writing the codes for displaying it, I would like to see if the data is getting added to realm. Is there anyway to Log the contents in the realm so that I know its not empty? I will post the code I have used for adding data to realm  below

```
private void addDataToRealm(DBPurchase model) {
        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        DBPurchase dbPurchaseModel = new DBPurchase();

        dbPurchaseModel.setCreatedAt(model.getCreatedAt());
        dbPurchaseModel.setLastUpdatedAt(model.getLastUpdatedAt());
        purchaseRealmList.add(dbPurchaseModel);
        mRealm.insertOrUpdate(dbPurchaseModel); 
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
        //purchaseFinalDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        id++;

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"value stored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend setting up and using [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) or [Realm Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realm-browser/id1007457278?mt=12) (if you're on a Mac). This is definitely worth the time to set up as print debugging will cost you way more time in the long run.

Comment: thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821570/accessing-realm-database-across-activities please go through this question as well.